# I've changed my site's domain, created a redirect, but old URLs result in 404

Tags: domains, htaccess, 301-redirect

I've changed the domain of my site, created a redirect, but it seems to work only partially. That is, when I go to `example.co.il` (old) I do get to `example.biz` (new).

But when I go to `example.co.il/just-a-nice-webpage-111` I get a 404?

Please tell me what can cause it, here is my domain.co.il folder htacess syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.biz/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Such questions are OT here. System and network administration -- Server Fault participants are much more likely to know the technical details on topics such as DNS and Apache configuration than people who answer questions here.

Comment: @Rob Not really. We answer questions like this all the time and the questions are not put on hold. This is primarily a question about an error in a redirect using .htaccess.

Comment: Does it redirect? Does `example.biz/just-a-nice-webpage-111` exist? Do the old and new domains both resolve to the same site?

Comment: @closetnoc Yes, I've seen that, but it's still against the rules I quoted and the question is directly in line with what serverfault is for. I've also seen HTML and CSS questions here, which are specifically OT, but, when I flag them, I'm told there's nothing wrong with that despite those, too, being specifically off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to work, you must retain the `example.co.il` domain and place the following redirect code in your `.htaccess` within the `example.co.il` web root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.biz/$1 [L,R=301]
```

*You do not need to check the host name.*

If you make a request for a page that does not exist on domain.biz you will get a 404 error as you should. This is correct.